# Don't understand <input> "id" property in Django tutorial

Tags: django, forms

I have the following code from the Django tutorial:

```
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
```

And there is something I don't understand.

The value of the `id` property of `input` is `choice{{ forloop.counter }}`. So, it will be something like this: *choice1, choice2 etc...*

And in the `views.py` I have the following line:

```
selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
```

But `pk` must be a number. 
How it works here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is used only for the label. It's not used in the data the form sends to the server. The value of the radio button (`value="{{ choice.id }}"`, a plain number) is what's sent.

In other words, the id and the line in the views.py file are not related.